# Error converting data type varchar to int error? 

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

can anyone tel me the reason for this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int error?

I see it while inserting values from ASP page to SQL 2000

Comment: Provide the **exact** (cut and pasted) error message.   Some code wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert strings to integers if they are not made entirely from numbers.

So, if you try to convert `aaa` to an int, this will fail. If you try to convert the varchar `123` to an int, it will work.